# Two Devise Models Link together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models, working separately. 
I would like to link_to using first devise user, second devise user id...

Having problem finding id when I click to 1.second devise user

Ex.
Loged in 1 first devise user, id 1

show:

```
 1.second devise user, <%= link_to ??? %>
 2.second devise user, <%= link_to ??? %>
 3.second devise user, <%= link_to ??? %>
```

And what would be controller?

Comment: really 2 devise models? Then please provider 2 model names.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are a admin and you want to log in as a user

but on my **/app/controllers/admins/users_controller.rb** I have

```
class Admins::UsersController < AdminController
def login_as
    sign_in(users.find(params[:id]), :bypass => true)
    redirect_to users_root_path
  end
end
```

then on my view I pass in the user id of the user that i want to log in as

```
User.all.each do |u|
  = simple_form_for :user, :url => admins_login_as_user_path, :html =>{:target => '_blank'} do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :id, u.id.to_s
  = f.button :submit, :value => t(:login_as), :class => 'btn btn-small btn-info'
```

I hope that this helps.